# Unexpectedly Found nil On TableView delegate and datasource after fetching data via API call

Tags: swift, uitableview

I am trying to display list of items in a tableview. The items are getting by making an API call and after parsing the json response. I am getting "Unexpectedly Found nil" error when I ran the project even before making the network call
Error is showing in this line
feedTableView.delegate = self
feedTableView.datasource = self

Please help me on this. Thank you in advance

**ViewController looks like this :**

```
class FeedViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var feedTableView: UITableView!
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setUpTableView()
        configureActivityIndicator()
        initViewModel()
    }
 func initViewModel() {
        viewModel = FeedViewModel()
        viewModel?.updatingStatus = { [weak self] () in
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            let isLoading = self?.viewModel?.isLoading ?? false
                if isLoading {
                    self?.activityIndicator.startAnimating()
                    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2) {
                        self?.feedTableView.alpha = 0
                        }
                    } else {
                        self!.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
                        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2) {
                        self?.feedTableView.alpha = 1.0
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        viewModel?.reloadFeedTableView = { [weak self] () in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self?.feedTableView.reloadData()
            }
        }
        viewModel?.fetchFeed()
    }
    
    func setUpTableView() {
        feedTableView?.register(FeedCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "id")
        feedTableView.delegate = self **Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping..** 
        feedTableView.dataSource = self
        feedTableView?.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
        feedTableView?.estimatedRowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
    }
}
extension FeedViewController: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return viewModel?.numberOfCellModels ?? 0
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        guard let cell = tableView
            .dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "id", for: indexPath)
        as? FeedCell else {
            fatalError("FeedCell typecast ")
        }
        if let cellModel = viewModel?.getCellAtRow(indexPath: indexPath) {
            cell.configure(feed: cellModel)
        }
        return cell
    }
}
```

**ViewModelClass**

```
class FeedViewModel {
    
    // MARK: - Properties

private let serviceProvider: ServiceProvider<EndPoint>

var reloadFeedTableView: (() -> Void) = {}
var updatingStatus: (() -> Void) = {}

init(serviceProvider: ServiceProvider<EndPoint> = ServiceProvider()) {
    self.serviceProvider = serviceProvider
}

private var cellViewModels = [FeedCellModel]() {
    didSet {
        self.reloadFeedTableView()
    }
}
var numberOfCellModels: Int {
    return cellViewModels.count
}
var isLoading: Bool = false {
    didSet {
        updatingStatus()
    }
}

func fetchFeed() {
    self.isLoading = true
    serviceProvider.load(endPoint: .fetchFeed,
                         decodeType: [Feed].self) { [weak self] response in
        guard let self = self else { return }
        
        switch response {
        case.failure(let error):
            print("Error occured\(error)")
        case .success(let feed):
            self.processFetchedData(feed: feed)
            self.isLoading = false
        }
    }
}

func processFetchedData(feed: [Feed]) {
    var cellModel = [FeedCellModel]()
    for feedItem in feed {
        let model = FeedCellModel(with: feedItem)
        cellModel.append(model)
    }      
    self.cellViewModels = cellModel
 
}

func getCellAtRow(indexPath: IndexPath) -> FeedCellModel {
    return cellViewModels[indexPath.row]
}
```

}

```
class FeedCellModel {
    let title: String?
    let date: String?
    let feedType: String?
    let imageUrl: String?

    
    init(with feed: Feed) {
        title = feed.title
        publishDate = feed.date
        feedType = feed.feedType
        imageUrl = feed.typeAttributes.imageUrl
    }
}
```

Comment: Is `feedTableView` correctly connected in your Storyboard or Xib? How did you create `FeedViewController`?

Comment: yes, feedTableView outlet is connected to FeedViewController, I even tried by removing and adding it again. Xib has correct identifier and I used this feedTableView?.register(FeedCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "id") to connect to tableview

Comment: How do you create the instance of `FeedViewController`?

Comment: Do you have somewhere in code `FeedViewController()`, ie `FeedViewController.init()`?

Comment: No I don't have this FeedViewController.init(). FeedViewController is the initial viewcontroller.    In scene delegate, willConnectTo function I have this
        guard let windowScene = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }
        
        let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: FeedViewController())
        window = UIWindow(frame: windowScene.coordinateSpace.bounds)
        window?.windowScene = windowScene
        window?.rootViewController = navController
        window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    }

Comment: Unrelated but why is `viewModel` optional? You can write `let viewModel = FeedViewModel()` on the top level of the view controller and then get rid of a bunch of question marks and optional bindings. And you are wrong, you **do** have `FeedViewController()` in `scene delegate` which is not the instance in the storyboard. This is the reason for the crash because the outlet is not connected.

Comment: `FeedViewController()`, that means `FeedViewController.init(), it's short hand syntax for it. If you use a Xib, you should init the `FeedViewController` with its related xib. `FeedViewController(nibname: "NameofTheXib", bundle: nil)` instead